# Shell command works in shell but not in shell script

Tags: shell, grep

i am trying to write a unix shell script to search for all header files for a given text, and then find how many times each header file is included in other files.

My problem is in the second part, the command which searches for includes in other files works from command line, but it doesn't print anything from the shell script.

```
array=( $(grep  'regexToSearch' -rl --include="*.h" pathToFiles) )

for item in "${array[@]}"
do
    filename=$(echo ${item} | grep -o '[^/]*.h')
    incstring="#include[ ]*\"$filename\""
    echo $incstring
    echo "--------------------"
    filelist=$(grep '$incstring' -rl --include=*.{h,cpp} pathToFiles)
    echo $filelist
    echo "--------------------"
done
```

The output is as follows:

```
#include[ ]*"header1.h"
--------------------
// Second grep output for first file should be here
--------------------
#include[ ]*"header2.h"
--------------------
// Second grep output for second file should be here
--------------------
#include[ ]*"header3.h"
--------------------
// Second grep output for third file should be here
--------------------
```

Comment: Why are you capturing `incstring` and `filelist` only to print them, rather than letting the commands that generate them emit directly to stdout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single quotes in this command:

```
    filelist=$(grep '$incstring' -rl --include=*.{h,cpp} pathToFiles)
```

Single quotes inhibit variable expansion.  That is, you're looking for the literal string `$incstring` rather than the contents of that variable.  This command, as shown here, *would not have worked on the command line* either.

From the `bash(1)` man page:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the  quotes.   A  single
>   quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

Replace the single quotes with double quotes:

```
    filelist=$(grep "$incstring" -rl --include=*.{h,cpp} pathToFiles)
```

Comment: You're converting `filelist` from an array (in the original) to a string, which substantially changes its meaning. Not that it was being put into an array _correctly_ (the output was just being string-split, with all the bugs/misfeatures that implies), so this is not actually more wrong... but it might be a better solution to form the array the Right Way instead.

Comment: Also, `--include="*.h"` is actually the desired usage. Check the man page for GNU `grep` -- it expects, and evaluates, literal patterns.

Comment: sorry -- not "literal patterns", but "literal glob patterns". In short, the desired usage for --include is NOT shell evaluation, but `fnmatch()`-style matching within grep's recursion code.

Answer (score 0):

First, the way you're forming the array is not robust -- if you had a header file containing a character from `IFS`, a wildcard character, or the like, it would cause some rather surprising failures.

```
pathToFiles=.

# form the headers array in a manner robust against all possible filenames
headers=()
while IFS='' read -r -d '' filename; do
  headers+=( "${filename#${pathToFiles}/}" )
done < <(grep -e "$regexToSearch" -Z -rl --include='*.h' "$pathToFiles")

for header in "${headers[@]}"; do
  echo "--- ${header}"
  # instead of capturing content, emit it directly to stdout
  grep -F -e '#include "'"$header"'"' -rl --include='*.h' --include='*.cpp' "$pathToFiles"
  echo "---"
done
```

The version given here doesn't allow multiple spaces between the `#include` string and the filename; this is in order to support `grep -F`, which treats strings as literal rather than regular expressions, thereby avoiding the potential corner case where filenames inject undesired expressions into content.